# How to fix external HDD bad-sector?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I can access the HDD, and I can copy/cut/paste files, until I reach some place in the HDD (I think around the 60GB mark), and I there are also bad sectors at other places.

HDD Regenerator didn't help me. Is there anyway I can fix the HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) did wonders for me, there's a video on that page that goes into it really well.

Basically what it does as I understand it, is it goes through and marks the bad sectors as bad and moves the files that are there to good locations on the drive and then prevents the drive from writing to those bad locations in the future.

Comment: There is more involved then just moving the data.  SpinRite can actually determine if a sector is good or bad, and if it determines its good, actually force the hdd to view the sector as good.  If its bad then yes, it moves the data, and forces hdd to mark it bad.  Its also able to on a bad sector ( depends on how badly the data is corrupted ) recover data by trial and error based on a checksum.  A given sector has a certain number of checksum bytes, its able to by brute force, figure out what the missing bytes are.  If your outside of the checksum your out of luck through.